# How to export "specific part of result" from json output of a API request which has a limit for results per API query into a text file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am working on a python script that will take specific part of a API response which is in JSON and print it to the text file each result in a new line.
This is the trickiest part i am confused about,
- Each API Request returns only 500 results, for which i have to get all the available results to write to text file.

I was successful in fetching the first batch of 500 results to write to a text file but i would like to know how to loop through the multiple requests to get next results until all available results are done and write them to a text file. Any help would he appreciated thanks.

```
import requests
import json
import re


apiurl =  'http://redacted.com?xxx=yyy&limit=500'
response = requests.get(apiurl).json()
response_dump = json.dumps(response)
response_data = json.loads(response_dump)
with open('results.txt', 'a') as file:
    for lines in response_data['result']:
        rsplit = re.sub(r'"(.{64})"', r"\1", lines)
        file.writelines("%s\n"  % rsplit)
```

Updated Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json
import re

apiurl =  'http://redacted.com?xxx=yyy&limit=500'
response = requests.get(apiurl).json()
with open('results.txt', 'a') as file:
    for lines in response['result']:
        rsplit = re.sub(r'"(.{64})"', r"\1", lines)
        file.writelines("%s\n"  % rsplit)
```

Sample JSON Data

```
{"xxx": xxx, "limit": 5, "result": ["result_to_get", "result_to_get", "result_to_get", "result_to_get", "result_to_get"]}
```

This above is code i wrote to get first 500 results, i want this made like to write all the results until it reaches end to a text file.

Comment: why making double conversion of json data?

Comment: Sorry, but i am utterly new to python. I got this far with help of tutorials online.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: I fixed the multiple conversion thing. it works fine with requests.json method. thanks.Updated the code above.

Comment: *"i am failing in looping through the requests..."* Please be more specific. How exactly are you failing? Are you getting an error message? If so, please include the full traceback in the question. If the code is behaving in an unexpected way, please describe what it is doing and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I mean like i didn't know where to loop through to begin with :( it would be helpful if someone can provide an idea. @glibdud

Comment: @Cryx Your `for` loop at first glance looks correct based on the information given. If it's not working, you're going to need to provide more information on how exactly it's failing.

Comment: @glibdud the above code works perfectly fine for grabbing first 500 results from API and writing it to the file, what i don't know is "how to implement a logic that can repeat the same process for all other results(next 500 and so on) untill the end of all the results" - 500 is the query limit per request.